# Replacing the SSD on a Dell Latitude E7270

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dell-latitude

I bought a 512 GB SSD from the Dell store for the E7270. When I opened up my laptop to replace my 128 GB SSD, I found that it was much smaller than the one I bought. All the tutorials I found online show how to remove the small SSD, but none show how to put in the large size one.

Comment: You can’t. You’ve purchased the wrong drive. Please specify exactly what you purchased. The 7270 uses an optional m.2 drive, but I’m not sure if that your laptop is equipped with that. You need to specify the service tag of the laptop so we can look up the exact specs.

Comment: You've most likely bought a 3.5mm SSD, which is larger than a 2.5mm SSD.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 regular sata SSD drives are measured in inches, not mm. And they don’t make them in 3.5” size. They make them in 2.5” size and you use an adapter if you need 3.5”. This doesn’t apply at all to the OP as this is a laptop that uses newer style mSATA or m.2 pci-e drives.

Comment: Ah, apologies. Looks like I need to brush up on my SSD knowledge!

Comment: have you bought now the correct SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to this test](https://www.notebookcheck.com/Test-Dell-Latitude-12-E7270-Notebook.167676.0.html), the SSD is a [M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) SSD

[image]

and it looks like bought a normal 2,5" SATA SSD. So buy a new SATA SSD in M.2  2280 form factor.